# How to remove the WARNING: replace module <module> in Julia

Tags: file, include, julia

I have a couple Julia files within a directory, namely

```sh
FolderName
|
|---main.jl
|---VectorFunctions.jl
|---MatrixFunctions.jl
```

The following is the structure for the files:

**VectorFunctions.jl**

```
module VectorFunctions
    # functions...
end
```

**MatrixFunctions.jl**

```
include("VectorFunctions.jl")

module MatrixFunctions
    # functions...
end
```

**main.jl**

```
include("VectorFunctions.jl")
include("MatrixFunctions.jl")

# Using the functions defined in both files...
```

Running the code with `julia main.jl` in my terminal, I get the following:

```sh
WARNING: replacing module VectorFunctions.

=== Desired Output ===
```

If I remove the include to **VectorFunctions.jl** in **main.jl**, the error disappears (I suspect because **VectorFunctions** is not being included again). Is there a way to get around this WARNING and still keep my my additional include in **main.jl**?

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Przemysław is correct. Note that `include` works as if you did copy-paste of the code from one place to another. So - using `include` you act as-if you copy-pasted the same code twice into your program.

However, note that:

1. If you turned `VectorFunctions` into a package ([here](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/) is an instruction how to do it), then instead of `include`, you would write `using VectorFunctions` and you could write it as many times as you like without a problem.
2. Alternatively you could write the following code instead of `include("VectorFunctions.jl")`, note though that it is not something that normally you would do (the approach that Przemysław describes or creating a package are recommended); the approach below assumes that the only thing that VectorFunctions.jl file holds is `VectorFunctions` module:

```
if isdefined(@__MODULE__, :VectorFunctions)
    VectorFunctions isa Module || error("VectorFunctions is present and it is not a Module")
else
    include("VectorFunctions.jl")
end
```

(again - be warned that this is not something that is recommended to do; I just give it to show you that it is possible to avoid reloading the same module into the current module twice)

Answer (score 1):

Your module `VectorFunctions` is defined two times what obviously does not make sense.

Simply remove the following  line from `MatrixFunctions.jl`:

```
include("VectorFunctions.jl")
```

Comment: It then gives me the error `ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: VectorFunctions not defined`. It might help to say that there is a function named `dot_product` within **VectorFunctions.jl** and within **MatrixFunctions.jl**, I am calling it using `VectorFunctions.dot_product(v1, v2)`.

Comment: maybe you have some other code somewhere. It is enough to load code with a module once. You do it twice and hence get a warning.